# Virtual Machines Critical Errors on Boot

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Firstly, thank you for taking the time to read my question.

I am brand new to superuser and Oracle Virtualbox 5.12.1.

**Host:** Windows 7 64 Bit **Guest OS:** Ubuntu 16.04.1, FreeDOS 1.1, Tails 2.5,
Edit: Host is a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 240

The issue is identical across the guest virtual machines. It boots up without error until it gets to the install screen. I can not maneuver using the keyboard and the mouse does not work ( in fact, I have never successfully moved the keyboard or mouse in one of the VMs). The automatic boot timers never move: the 7 seconds for tails and the 50 for dos, so I am assuming that they are hanging immediately upon booting. Virtualbox does not freeze and it can capture the mouse and release using the host key. Upon testing today however, it does the same thing but eventually recieves a critical error and force closes.

**For each of the three VM's, I have tried:**

- Upping and lowering the base memory (while ensuring it does not go over available mem)
- redownloading all the isos.
- Enabling/Disabling 3D acceleration, APIC,
- reinstalling virtualbox

I am literally brand new to virtualization and after extensive online research trying to find an answer I've come to the conclusion that to effect all virtual machines using different guests can only mean that **I am doing something fundamentally wrong**. I believe I am following the virtual box installation instructions for each OS provided to the letter, but clearly I am not. I will certainly attempt to provide more specific information, but the issue itself is quite broad. Anyone who can help steer me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you accessing the host directly or remotely? I've heard of issues where remotely accessing the host via LogMeIn can cause this issue. RDP seems to work fine. Being directly on the host itself is better.

Comment: Accessing directly yes! Thank for the reply. I'm literally trying to achieve just basic functionality, then I will try the cooler things like accessing remotely.

Comment: It seems very strange to me that you can't even get the keyboard working. I've had mouse trouble in a VM before, but never keyboard problems. Is there anything special about it? Like is it a standard US 101-key keyboard? Is it wireless? Have you confirmed that typing does nothing even when the VM has the mouse captured?

Comment: Exactly, standard lenovo thinkpad keyboard. I've added that to the question. I'm not entirely sure however that it is a keyboard issue just because it is locking up immediately, like with the boot timers never going down even a second.

Comment: Make sure you have virtualization enabled in the firmware.

Comment: I think the latest version of VirtualBox is 5.0.24. How do you happen to have 5.12.1??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have virtualization enabled in the firmware. – Michael Hampton 43 mins ago

I had disregarded this as a possibility considering I have used an older version of virtualbox on this environment, but it was in fact the issue. Thanks for all the help everyone.